# Change HTTP Post login Adrress in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to change the HTTP post login address.

Right now the default "/login" is set and works but I want to change it to "/users/login"

This is my HttpSecurity configuration.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/users/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


}
```

The application class is nothing special.

```
package com.auth0.samples.authapi;

import..
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```